# SyntaxError: Unexpected number at Object.parse (native) at uc

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, jekyll

I've got a jekyll site, and I'm integrating some Angular components.

I'm trying to refactor a bunch of data from the Angular controller into a .json file and I'm catching this error in the browser:

SyntaxError: Unexpected number at Object.parse (native)

```
var app = angular.module('portfolio', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});

app.controller('portfolioCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('../projects/projects.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.projects = data;
    });
    $scope.orderProp = 'age';
}]);
```

Comment: can you share the json? if the output inform JSON.parse('{"val": ["", "{\"7\":\"14\"}]"]}') the above error will be occur?

Comment: the error may be occurred because of backslashes, you should be escape those slashes `JSON.parse('{"a":"{\"465\":\"85\"}"}')` into `JSON.parse('{"a":"{\\"465\\":\\"85\\"}"}')`

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with one of the data types.  Apparently JSON doesn't like dates.  I had a value like `2015-09-15` with the hope that I could sort the data by their date, but I ended up turning it into a string and it works fine now.